# How to understand the recursive function call in MonadWriter Typeclass

Tags: haskell

In the `mtl` library, I see the definition of `MonadWriter`:

```
class (Monoid w, Monad m) => MonadWriter w m | m -> w where
#if __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ >= 707
    {-# MINIMAL (writer | tell), listen, pass #-}
#endif
    -- | @'writer' (a,w)@ embeds a simple writer action.
    writer :: (a,w) -> m a
    writer ~(a, w) = do
      tell w
      return a

    -- | @'tell' w@ is an action that produces the output @w@.
    tell   :: w -> m ()
    tell w = writer ((),w)
```

So `writer` and `tell` recursively calls each other. But I can't understand how that works. Is there a stop condition? Does this work because of the laziness of Haskell? Could anyone shine a light on it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note the [`MINIMAL` annotation](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/8.6.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#minimal-pragma):

```
{-# MINIMAL (writer | tell), listen, pass #-}
```

This tells GHC which class methods need to be implemented to make a complete instance. Normally, this set of methods is inferred by the compiler—it’s just the set of methods that don’t have default implementations—but in some situations, it’s useful to specify it explicitly. This is one such situation.

The `MINIMAL` annotation for `MonadWriter` says that `listen` and `pass` must always be implemented, and this makes sense, since those methods don’t have any default implementations. It then goes on to say something more interesting: either `writer` *or* `tell` must be implemented, but not necessarily both.

This works out, since if an instance supplies an implementation of `writer`, then the default implementation for `tell` will be used to implement it in terms of the provided `writer` implementation. Likewise, the inverse will be true if an instance supplies `tell` but not `writer`. The `MINIMAL` annotation protects an instance from supplying an implementation of *neither*, so no complete instance can ever have both default implementations in use at once.